# 401 Unauthorized response when sending a request in cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, gitlab

I'm trying to get my gitlab project issues using GitLab API I've tried this
but it seems not be working

```
<?php

$url = "https://git.exemple.com/api/v4/issues";
$ch = curl_init($url);


curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
        array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: PRIVATE-TOKEN xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($e = curl_error($ch)){
    echo $e;
}
else{
    $decoded = json_decode($resp,true);
    print_r($decoded);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

this the response I get

```
Array ( [message] => 401 Unauthorized )
```

Comment: **Not working** That I am afraid is not a helpful description. WHat IS it doing? What is it NOT doing? What do you expect? What do you get??

Comment: I'm trying to get my issues from my GitLab project and display them in an HTML table but using GitLab API but I was having troubles with Authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple reading of the manual

[Personal/project access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#personalproject-access-tokens)

suggests that your header should be:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));
```

Comment: No worries. It is customary around here that if you found the answer useful, to press the 'up' arrow next to it and if it solves your problem, to press the 'check' mark too.