# Unable to create user in GitLab using REST API through PHP (Error: 401 Unauthorized)

Tags: php, rest, curl, post, gitlab-api

I am facing an error **(401 Unauthorized)** while trying to create user in GitLab using Curl REST API through POST command in PHP. But when I use the same inputs through POSTMAN, it works. Any support would be appreciated.

Below is my code

```
function connect2git()
{
    $userdata = array('name'=>'xxxxx', 
                'username'=>'yyyyy', 'email'=>'xxx.yyy@zzz.com, 
                   'password'=>'abcde');
    $data_json = json_encode($userdata);
    $authorization = "Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://abcde.xyz.net/api/v4/users");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    
    // Parameters for debugging
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    
    $certificate_location = "C:\\Users\\Test";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, $certificate_location);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $certificate_location);
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $head = "";
    $info = "";
    
    if (curl_errno($curl)){
        $response = 'GIT Server Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    }
    else {
      //$skip = intval(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
      //$response = substr($response,$skip);
      $response = json_decode($response, true);
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    //$teststr = gettype($response);
    return $response;
}
```

Attached is snapshot of my POSTMAN command:
[POSTMAN_snap_for_UserCreation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le57w.jpg)

Comment: please share what you post in postman (e.g. screenshot) so that we can compare

Comment: I have added the image in the post. Please check. Thank you

Comment: are you following this? https://docs.gitlab.com/14.0/ee/api/users.html#user-creation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [401 Unauthorized response when sending a request in cURL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67199401/401-unauthorized-response-when-sending-a-request-in-curl-php)
Is your 'Authorization: XXX' starting with 'Bearer '?

Comment: Thank you for the info. I tried with both(PRIVATE-TOKEN & Authorization) mentioned in the link. But that triggers another error: 400 Bad Request